# Bringing the plots into the web in R

Tags: plotly

I want to bring this plot into the web and then send it to some people. I used Plotly package in R. But it seems to do that I need to make a public account and the problem is that people will have access to the data sets as well. Is there another way to bring this plot into the web and share it with some people but doesn't allow them to download the data set?

```
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length,
        marker = list(size = 10,
                       color = 'rgba(255, 182, 193, .9)',
                       line = list(color = 'rgba(152, 0, 0, .8)',
                                   width = 2))) %>%
  layout(title = 'Styled Scatter',
         yaxis = list(zeroline = FALSE),
         xaxis = list(zeroline = FALSE))
```

Also it seems if I save it plot locally by using "htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as.widget(p), "index.html")" function then I can not share it with some people. Am I right?

Comment: I use plotly with python (where there is an option plotly offline) and I never had problem sharing the .html file saved locally

Comment: @ user32185 , thanks for the reply. When you save the html file (forexample on your desktop) then what would you do with this plot as you can not share it with others. Do you bring it into the power point?

Comment: I publish or include on a jupyter presentation. I never tried with a power point.

Comment: @ user32185,  Do you publish it through your account in plot.ly website? The problem is that when we publish in through our account, people can download the data set through the plot. Any solution for this issue?

Comment: I don't have a plot.ly account. I publish the html inside an iframe on any website I need.